# How many bytes is \n\r?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, newline, byte

I have a .NET app that is trying to ftp a file but I'm ending up with 1 extra byte per line. My line separator is Environment.NewLine, which I believe translates into \n\r. How many bytes is that?

Answer (score 32):

It depends on the encoding. In 8-bit encodings as well as UTF-8 it's 2 bytes. In UCS-2 or UTF-16 it's 4 bytes. In UCS-4 or UTF-32 it's 8 bytes.

But the problem is that you're probably FTPing in ASCII mode instead of IMAGE mode.

Comment: Aren't UCS-4 and UTF-32 the same thing?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: For now. But that's not required to always be true.

Answer (score 10):

It's 2 bytes, but it should be `\r\n` not `\n\r` on windows OSs

Answer (score 7):

In ASCII encoding, \n is the Newline character 0x0A (decimal 10), \r is the Carriage Return character 0x0D (decimal 13).

As Jack has said already, the correct sequence is CR-LF, not vice versa.

FTP is probably adding LF characters to your stream if they are placed incorrectly and you are transmitting the file as Text.

Answer (score 2):

Two bytes.  One for \n and one for \r.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the implied question:

To use binary-transfer rather than ascii-transfer in C#, use

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://example.com"));
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

\n\r is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of future readers; you can determine how many bytes are in a given string (or string value) via the following:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("SomeString");
```

In this case;

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(Environment.NewLine);
// OR
Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("\n\r");
```

.NET uses `Unicode` unless otherwise specified; for example with an `XmlSerializer` you can specify the encoding.

Remember to use the proper encoding when you are attempting to count the number of bytes since it is different with each encoding:

> - An ASCII character in 8-bit ASCII encoding is 8 bits (1 byte), though it can fit in 7 bits.
> - An ISO-8895-1 character in ISO-8859-1 encoding is 8 bits (1 byte).
> - A Unicode character in UTF-8 encoding is between 8 bits (1 byte) and 32 bits (4 bytes).
> - A Unicode character in UTF-16 encoding is between 16 (2 bytes) and 32 bits (4 bytes), though most of the common characters take 16 bits. This is the encoding used by Windows internally.
> - A Unicode character in UTF-32 encoding is always 32 bits (4 bytes).
> - An ASCII character in UTF-8 is 8 bits (1 byte), and in UTF-16 - 16 bits.
> - The additional (non-ASCII) characters in ISO-8895-1 (0xA0-0xFF) would take 16 bits in UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

FTP software usually offer a binary and a text transfer mode. In text mode newline translation occurs during the transfer. This might be valid information, depending on what your problem is and why you asked the question.